# PHP - Função While

Tags: php, laravel

Bom dia, estou com uma dúvida em relação à função `while` no meu projeto **Laravel**.

Funciona assim:
Usuário tem um número X de créditos - coluna créditos no banco de dados. Ele upa um arquivo xlsx com os dados de novos usuários, o sistema conta o número de linhas (`$rows`) e abre um `foreach` para acessar cada linha e criar um usuário.

A ideia é que cada usuário valesse 1 crédito - ou seja - pra cada usuário criado (ou cada linha lida) o crédito do usuário_criador reduzisse em 1 até que chegasse no valor de 0 e o sistema parasse.

```
$credito = $usuarioLogado->creditos; 
$linhas_tabela = $dadosPlanilha->count(); 
do { (código de criação do novo usuário) $credito--; } while ($credito >= $linhas_tabela;
```

Queria que quando o número de créditos for 0 ou menor que o número de linhas, o sistema parasse e apresentasse uma mensagem. Não sei se está certo isso que eu fiz, mas fui dando uma pesquisada pela internet.

Comment: Qual seria a dúvida? Tem como postar o que desenvolveu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É bom sempre assimilar o código com texto interpretativo para não confundir nesse início, no caso abaixo:

```
do    = Faça
While = Enquanto
```

> Faça a criação do novo usuário e decremente a variável **$credito**
>   enquanto a variável **$credito** for maior ou igual ao número de linhas da
>   planilha.

```
 $credito       = $usuarioLogado->creditos; //1
 $linhas_tabela = $dadosPlanilha->count(); //2
 do { 
      (código de criação do novo usuário) 
      $credito--; 
 }while($credito >= $linhas_tabela);
```

Não sei se pesquei sua idéia, mas para a lógica que quer atingir o código postado acima, o laço **DO WHILE**  não ira funcionar bem. Seria melhor usar um **FOR** e um **break** como abaixo:

```
 $credito       = $usuarioLogado->creditos; 
 $linhas_tabela = $dadosPlanilha->count(); 
 for($i=0;$i<$linhas_tabela;$i++){
     if($credito == 0) break;
     (código de criação do novo usuário) 
     $credito--;            
 }
```

Para **$i** começando em zero, sendo **$i** menor que **$linhas_tablela** e a cada interação do loop **FOR** incrementando mais um na variável **$i**. O macete aqui é o uso do **break** dentro da condição **IF** para escapar o laço de repetição caso **$credito** tenha atingido o valor de zero.

Atualização: verifique novamente toda a sua rotina, conforme debug da imagem abaixo o código que postei funciona perfeito!

[image: Debug Rotina]

Por favor edite sua pergunta e adicione o código php dentro dela para seguir as regras do stack.

Comment: Eu adicionei esse código no meu sistema e não funcionou como eu gostaria. Ele cria os usuários, mas não leva em consideração os créditos do usuário criador. Se o usuário tiver 4 créditos, o sistema cria o número de linhas independente desses 4 créditos. Posso colocar o link do pastebin com o código? Aqui não cabe,

Comment: Altera sua pergunta e adiciona o resto do código ou cria outra pergunta e notifique aqui por comentário!